# Adding an onClick button into reactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, onclick

**Hi Friends**

I'm currently working on a landing page. The functionality is taken care of in reactJS (which I am relatively unfamilar with). I am having trouble adding an onClick to the button in order to take me to the next page of my project.

**Here is my JS**

```
var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }

var FancyButton = function (_React$Component) {
    _inherits(FancyButton, _React$Component);

    function FancyButton() {
        _classCallCheck(this, FancyButton);

        return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (FancyButton.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(FancyButton)).apply(this, arguments));
    }

    _createClass(FancyButton, [{
        key: 'render',
        value: function render() {
            // Mask id and styling
            // need unique id's for multiple buttons
            var maskId = 'mask_1';
            var maskStyle = '#fancy-masked-element_' + maskId + ' { mask: url(#' + maskId + '); -webkit-mask: url(#' + maskId + ')}';

            var buttonStyle = {
                width: this.props.width,
                height: this.props.height
            };

            var fancyFrontStyle = {
                transform: 'rotateX(0deg) translateZ(' + this.props.height / 2 + 'px )'
            };

            var fancyBackStyle = {
                transform: 'rotateX(90deg) translateZ( ' + this.props.height / 2 + 'px )'
            };



            // SVG attributes
            var textTransform = 'matrix(1 0 0 1 ' + this.props.width / 2 + ' ' + this.props.height / 1.6 + ')';
            var viewBox = '0 0 ' + this.props.width + ' ' + this.props.height;

            return React.createElement(
                'div',
                { className: 'fancy-button',
                    style: buttonStyle,
                    ref: 'fancyButton' },
                React.createElement(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'fancy-flipper' },
                    React.createElement(
                        'div',
                        { className: 'fancy-front', style: fancyFrontStyle },
                        React.createElement(
                            'svg',
                            {
                                height: this.props.height,
                                width: this.props.width,
                                viewBox: viewBox },
                            React.createElement(
                                'defs',
                                null,
                                React.createElement(
                                    'mask',
                                    { id: maskId },
                                    React.createElement('rect', { width: '100%', height: '100%', fill: '#FFFFFF' }),
                                    React.createElement(
                                        'text',
                                        { className: 'mask-text button-text', fill: '#000000', transform: textTransform, fontFamily: '\'intro_regular\'', fontSize: this.props.fontSize, width: '100%', textAnchor: 'middle', letterSpacing: '1' },
                                        this.props.buttonText
                                    )
                                )
                            ),
                            React.createElement(
                                'style',
                                null,
                                maskStyle
                            ),
                            React.createElement('rect', { id: 'fancy-masked-element_' + maskId, fill: this.props.color, width: '100%', height: '100%' })
                        )
                    ),
                    React.createElement(
                        'div',
                        { className: 'fancy-back', style: fancyBackStyle },
                        React.createElement(
                            'svg',
                            {
                                height: this.props.height,
                                width: this.props.width,
                                viewBox: viewBox },
                            React.createElement('rect', { stroke: this.props.color,
                                strokeWidth: this.props.borderWidth,
                                fill: 'transparent',
                                width: '100%',
                                height: '100%' }),
                            React.createElement(
                                'text',
                                { className: 'button-text', transform: textTransform, fill: this.props.color, fontFamily: '\'intro_regular\'', fontSize: this.props.fontSize, textAnchor: 'middle', letterSpacing: '1' },
                                this.props.buttonText,

                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
        }
    }]);

    return FancyButton;
}(React.Component);

FancyButton.defaultProps = {
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    width: 410,
    height: 100,
    fontSize: 42,
    borderWidth: 15,
    buttonText: 'MYSTUDY'

};

React.render(React.createElement(FancyButton, null), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Thus far I have tried to add an A tag in my html and reference it further in my JS

```
function App() {
    {
      window.location.href = "homepageDEMO.php";
    }
}
```

This also didn't work, Probably because it is ordinary Js and I realized the function I created was not referencing the button I need.

I then tried to add an onClick to the function FancyButton and I also tried by adding a reference to the page I want to go to. Neither worked

```
    function FancyButton() {
    _classCallCheck(this, FancyButton);
        {
      window.location.href = "index2.html";
    }
    return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (FancyButton.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(FancyButton)).apply(this, arguments));
}
```

This last code made the page which held my landing page go to the page I wanted to go to with the button on my landing page.

```
function FancyButton() {
        _classCallCheck(this, FancyButton);

        return _possibleConstructorReturn("webApp.php", (FancyButton.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(FancyButton)).apply(this, arguments));
    }
```

Anyone have the answer to my problems?

---

---

### EDIT

With help from the comments I have found the solution. I added the onclick syntax into the fancy-button class and it worked like a charm. Thank you all

```
return React.createElement(
                'div',
                { className: 'fancy-button',
                    style: buttonStyle,
                    onClick: () => window.location.href = "index2.html",
                    ref: 'fancyButton' },
```

Comment: Any Ideas? It's probably very simple but i'm very new to this

Comment: Try: `                    React.createElement(
                        'div',
                        { className: 'someClass', style: someStyle, onClick: () => window.location.href = "index2.html" },
...`

Comment: Hi @HaiAlaluf , I added it into the fancy button class and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much

Comment: There is any reason you don't use JSX and es6?

Comment: @HaiAlaluf I've only recently being delving into the world of JSX and es6. There's a bit of a learning curve from what i'm used to so i'm just getting into the swing of things. Thanks for your help

Comment: In my opinion, developing with JSX will be much easier even if you don't know it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You use React.createElement(component, props, ...children)
You can simply add your redirect function to props using onClick property, it should look like that:

```
createReactClass({
    redirect: function() {
        window.location.href = "index2.html";
    }
    render: function() {
        ReactDOM.render(
            React.createElement(div,
                { ...otherProps, onClick: this.redirect },
                null)
            );
    }
});
```